# Контравариантность stream в Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

Который раз спотыкаюсь на стримы и интерфейсы в Java. Допустим у меня есть интерфейс `ToDeString` и класс `De`, который его имплементит. Этот класс имеет метод `List<De> getList()`, который возвращает объекты этого же класса `De`. Затем, я создаю такой стим:

```
de.getList().stream().map(d->d.getList().stream()).map(s-> streamToDeString(s))
```

Где `String streamToDeString(Stream<ToDeString> stream)`. Но так нельзя. Функция `streamToDeString` не принимает стримы типа `Stream<De>`, хотя `De` наследует `ToDeString`.

Разъясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Дженерики в джаве инвариантны, `List<X>` нельзя использовать как `List<Y>`, даже если X наследует/имплементирует Y. Вам необходимо развернуть вложенный стрим и работать с элементами напрямую, либо, при возможности, использовать wildcard types.

Comment: Или используйте `Kotlin` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно так нельзя ) И ни в одном нормальном языке так нельзя )

Чтобы это работало, вам эту ковариантность нужно явно указать:

`String streamToDeString(Stream<? extends ToDeString> stream)`

Вы наверное путаете это с такой формой:

`String func(ToDeString arg)` - Тогда действительно можно предеавать и наследников тоже.

Собственно само понятие ковариантности позволяет указать что List из наследников тоже будет наследником. Как то так.